# Wordpress: Render 2 terms in a taxonomy page

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

In wordpress, I want to render more than one term, in a taxonomy page in wordpress but its not woking at all. Is there a way to do so? If its not possible to loop, is there a url that renders two terms?

```
$query_args = array(
              'post_type' => 'shop',
              
              'tax_query' => array(
                'taxonomy' => 'floor',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('1f', 'b1f'),
            'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Comment: The code looks correct, so can you define "not working"? Do you see any error messages? It would be good if you could check that the taxonomy and term slugs are defined correctly. If that is all good, then please update your question to include the return value of the query. E.g. add `print_r($query); exit();` directly after `$query = new WP_Query` to view in page, or `error_log(print_r($query, true));` which will write the query results to the WordPress debug log, assuming debugging is enabled.